# ksoap2-android connecitong problems

Tags: android-ksoap2

so I am having a problem trying to send 6 variables to a web service (http://hydra.chorleywood.org/hydradevices/devicesmanagement.asmx)

I am using ksoap2-android in android running 4.2 API 17

My program crashes every time I press the button it is associated with. I have looked through many tutorials and have done just as they have but it just does not work for me whether i run it in eclipse or export and run it on my phone.

here is the relevant parts of the code

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://hydra.chorleywood.org";
private static final String URL="http://hydra.chorleywood.org/hydradevices/devicesmanagement.asmx"; 
private static final String METHOD1_SOAP_ACTION_URL = "http://hydra.chorleywood.org/addNewDevice";
private static final String METHOD_NAME1 = "addNewDevice";

final Button status_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.device_status);
status_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click

        // setting my variables
        String EUI64 = "EHF7980HY3G793HG393GF737GH80G7";
        String HashCode = "MB2GPD";
        int DeviceTypeID = 528391;
        String subType = "Weighing Scales";
        String Manufacturer = "Samsung";
        String SerialNumber = "8476403967";

        // setting connectionas
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        // setting informaiton to be sent
        request.addProperty("EUI64", EUI64);
        request.addProperty("HashCode", HashCode);
        request.addProperty("DeviceTypeID", DeviceTypeID);
        request.addProperty("subType", subType);
        request.addProperty("Manufacturer", Manufacturer);
        request.addProperty("SerialNumber", SerialNumber);

        // setting request to be sent out
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            try
            {
            androidHttpTransport.call(METHOD1_SOAP_ACTION_URL, envelope);
            //java.lang.String receivedString = (String)envelope.getResponse();
            //java.lang.Boolean receivedBoolean = (Boolean)envelope.getResponse();
            Object result = envelope.getResponse();

            /**if(receivedBoolean = true) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "testing toast";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }**/

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
    }
```

I have set the permission in the manifest 
I'm not certain what exactly is wrong, does anyone know?

I have tried different API's and that still did not work.
I would really appreciate any help on this topic, I have put a week into it so far and I'm just running in circles.

I have literally copy pasted other peoples web services with (what i believe to be an active server) and tried running their exact code and that does not seem to work also. Perhaps that will help you figure out the problem I am having.

Many thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Thread for android version higher then 3.0.
Try [this.](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the **network** in **main** thread. Android throws the NetworkOnMainThreadException on these occasions.

Please check this question. [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

You need to access the network in a separate thread. ([Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html))